# ASP.NET Core 6 updating files without full publish on server?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

In my case, I just made some changes on startup of my ASP.NET Core 6 project and wanted to update the published files on the server (without full publish again), but unfortunately I couldn't find any answer for this.

Comment: Those source files get turned into a dll and you publish the dll. Are you thinking that the source files are published? There's no incrementalism inside of the dll itself.

Comment: In general ASP.NET Core starts to limit what you can do after publishing the artifacts, which is a good thing that eliminates lots of hurdles of ASP.NET 4.x. You might update views with extra configuration, https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/why-your-asp-net-core-views-are-not-updating-at-runtime but not other files.

Comment: @davidfowl what is the name of that dll file ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Your application gets turned into an asset that you can no longer change once deployed:

source files (*.cs) -> publish process -> *.dll files and static files (*.js/*.css etc)